# javascript source files are being loaded very slowly in browser context in an application with Java8 and Tomcat8

Tags: javascript, extjs, tomcat8

we have created an application using Extjs(UI side) and Java(serverside) with either Tomcat or Jetty as an application server.

Whenever we are trying to run our application with Java8 and Jetty its working fine but if we try to run it with java8 and Tomcat8, the loading activity of javascript files in browser context becomes very very slow.

I am not getting the reason. is there any issue in Tomcat8 as my application with java8 and jetty is working fine.

I have tested it on latest chrome.

If anybody has faced such issue, please suggest a way out of this problem.